# NUXT SSR using images

Tags: server-side-rendering, nuxtjs

I have an SSR application built in Nuxt. I am using renderRoute to render The Vue files since I need to send data to client side. Everything works fine but the static images are not being loaded in my application. I am using the following code to insert images in my vue file.

`<img src="~assets/img/picture.png">`

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/img/picture.png')">
```

Comment: this is not working as well. It seems I will have to add the static images to the server folder in SSR mode. Is there any other way to do this? It doesn't makes sense to move the whole assets folder to server folder

Answer (score 0):

Use dots to get relative parent folder path.

`<img src="../assets/img/picture.png">`

Or use `@` to denote parent folder.

`<img src="@/assets/img/picture.png">`

Comment: It says path not found with Nuxt.render